# UFT _User gets logged out of Application when browser is refreshed

Tags: browser, refresh, hp-uft

```
Browser("Browsername").Refresh
```

I am using this to refresh my application , Once the browser is refreshed the user is getting logged out of application. Any other way to check that  user is not logging off the appliation after browser refresh ?

Application is built on Angular JS and I am automation using UFT

Comment: What page is displayed when the user logs off ? and what page/title is displayed on browser refresh ? - if they are different then you can identify that user is logged out due to browser refresh and not by logging himself out

Comment: Login page is displayed when the user logs off...I want to refresh Reports page but once refresh is done it displays Login Page.. The problem is when i do it manually as in not using UFT ...application  doesn't gets logged off reports page is displayed... but through UFT its gets logged out.

Comment: It's strange, unless reports page is not on other URL/Pop page/Frame, this could happen - did you try simulating F5 Key ? does that help ?

Comment: I used both refresh and F5 Key .. I observed that when i individually run the refresh line it is getting refreshed and stays on reports page but when i include it in script and execute the complete script  , it is getting navigate to login page.

Comment: what i mean was simulating F5 key using sendkeys method in the script

Comment: I tried that .. Still after refresh it is going to login page